# Table with frequencies for multiple variables

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, frequency, spss

I want to re-produce with SPSS the table with frequencies, which I usually create with SQL.

Input: one table, 2 fields, both of them are strings.

SQL-Code:

```
SELECT A,B, COUNT(*) FROM TTABLE GROUP BY A,B
```

How can I make get the same table, but with SPSS-syntax.

CTABLES seems to work only with 1 field.

Answer (score 0):

After opening your table in SPSS I think this should do what you want:

```
DATASET DECLARE yourNewTable.
AGGREGATE /OUTFILE='yourNewTable'/BREAK=varA varB/N_BREAK=N.
```

Answer (score 0):

CTABLES handles any number of fields.  Use the canvas to lay out the table. Chou could put the variables to count across the top but choose to have the values down the side.  If you need more help, send me a small dataset to work with (jkpeck at gmail.com)